# Where to buy a similar Vietnam SIM card aimed for locals/expats (not for tourists) in HCMC?

Tags: legal, cellphones, thailand, vietnam, southeast-asia

I live in Thailand and use a dual SIM smartphone currently containing only one SIM card which is my local prepaid Thailand SIM card.

I already visited Vietnam twice; each time for a few days;
In both cases I bought a prepaid SIM card inside an airport;
Both SIM cards I bought were of *Mobifone* and aimed for tourists (for "one month") usage.

**Both aforementioned SIM cards contained similar specification:**

> #### 1) Web package
>
> - 4GB web bandwidth
> - 4MB web download speed
>
> #### 2) Telephony package
>
> - Unlimited incoming local phone calls
> - Unlimited incoming global phone calls
> - Unlimited outgoing local phone calls
> - Some possibility for outgoing global phone calls
>
> #### 3) SMS package
>
> - Unlimited incoming local SMSs
> - Unlimited incoming global SMSs
> - Unlimited outgoing local SMSs
> - Some possibility for outgoing global SMSs

<sub>By **unlimited incoming global SMSs** I could keep getting SMSs From Thailand based on my Thai phone number → from both my Thai cellular operator and Thai bank company (often based on their applications) and thus both top up my Thai prepaid SIM card and control my Thai bank account overseas.</sub>

### My questions

I need a SIM card for six months or one year with a similar specification but with;
**Unlimited internet bandwidth for fair/plausible use (non commercial use).**

I believe such SIM card will only be sold **outside** a Vietnam airport.

Where to buy a similar Vietnam SIM card aimed for locals/expats (not for tourists) in HCMC?

Comment: Given how frequently rates on SIM cards change around the world, we usually close them as a duplicate of a more generic question as its hard to keep answers up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy any of the available packages at any store in Vietnam, I am not an expert on the various packages but the one I have costs me about 20 usd per month and gives me more than I ever need every month and you can choose to pay monthly, every 6 months or yearly for the package and top up as needed just don’t think you can withdraw unused funds cause you cannot

I just came back from HCMC and in the stores where I asked there was no unlimited data plan available

But anyone can buy any of the available plans apart from plans that are invoiced after the fact.

Comment: @JohnDoea maybe I have misunderstood something here, are you talking about packages where you pay invoices after the fact? Or prepaid packages ? I never had an issue finding a pre paid package that suited my needs

Comment: @JohnDoea I am with you on that one, many years ago I was being a smart ass in northern Sweden way way up there and didn’t notice my online connected to a Finnish carrier and my invoice was massive, after that I only use prepaid cards even for my companies it’s just easier to control